# Can one supply an Arduino Zero's VIN pin with 5v?

Tags: power

The title pretty much says it all. I know that most Arduinos can do this, but I couldn't find very much information for the Zero. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. If you look at the schematics on the Arduino website you can see that the 3.3 volt regulator is connected to the 5 volt regulator. That means that if you feed 5 volts straight into the 5 volt pin it will go through the 3.3 volt regulator to supply the main chip.
Note that this is going into the 5 volt pin not the VIN pin which goes into the 5 volt regulator and would thus require a higher voltage than 5 volts.